# odata deep-level expand not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to perform a nested expand on one of my odata queries (3 levels) and am unable to get the expanded object to be returned.

Here are my classes:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Manager Manager { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProjectResource> ProjectResources { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectResource
{
    public int ProjectResourceId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Forecast> Forecasts { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Manager Manager { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProjectResource> ProjectResources { get; set; }
}

public class Manager
{
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Forecast
{
    public int ForecastId { get; set; }
    public ProjectResource ProjectResource { get; set; }
}
```

The following odata query works, and a list of `Projects` and their `Managers` is returned:

```
/Projects?$expand=Manager
```

I then tried this query, and it worked:

```
/Forecasts?$expand=ProjectResource($expand=Project)
```

Adding another level of expand:

```
/Forecasts?$expand=ProjectResource($expand=Project($expand=Manager))
```

And I get an error saying that I can only expand 2 levels. So I add this to my query and retry:

```
[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth=0)]
```

I don't get the error anymore, but the `Manager` for each `Project` is not included. Any idea on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 8):

I was struggling with the same problem.  Turns out that adding all of the entity sets during the configuration allows the `$expand` to work properly after 2 levels.
Add all your entity sets like this:

```
builder.EntitySet<Item>("Items");
builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
builder.EntitySet<Model>("Models");
builder.EntitySet<Type>("Types");
```

I also set [EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth=0)] as an attribute on the controller.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add all of the entity sets during the configuration allows the $expand to work properly after 2 levels.

The SO Question that claims that this issue is related to complex type is NOT valid.

Hope it helps save someone his time, just wasted 2 days because of this!

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer, and when Othman says 'all' entity sets he means ALL. Don't forget any entities that act as the 'join' in many to many relationships/navigation properties. After that, you will be able to query more than 2 deep. I sunk a half day into this before i got to this answer, thanks othman.

Answer (score 0):

I have added all required entity sets, but still, have the issue with 4th level :( Even commented all entity sets and the result was the same. Also added [EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 5)] to action. SQL Profiler shows correct entities and a proper amount of joins, but the response is not valid.